# Pyomo DataPortal Not Reading in Multi-Column CSV Properly

Tags: python, csv, pyomo

I am trying to read in a csv with multiple columns using the Pyomo DataPortal function `data.load` to initialize an index `i` but am running into an issue where I cannot select for the column I want using the `select` argument.

Here is the code I am running.

```
from pyomo.environ import *
model = AbstractModel()
model.i = Set()

data = DataPortal()
data.load(filename='fips.csv',select='fips',set=model.i)
```

The `fips.csv` file has multiple columns with FIPS code details. I'm trying to select the column called `fips`.

The error I am getting is the following.

```
Model declaration 'f' not found in returned query columns
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/cwayner/PycharmProjects/SeniorThesis/pyomo/dataportal/DataPortal.py", line 164, in load
    self._data_manager.read()
  File "/Users/cwayner/PycharmProjects/SeniorThesis/pyomo/dataportal/plugins/csv_table.py", line 58, in read
    self._set_data(tmp[0], tmp[1:])
  File "/Users/cwayner/PycharmProjects/SeniorThesis/pyomo/dataportal/TableData.py", line 117, in _set_data
    header_index.append(headers.index(str(i)))
ValueError: 'f' is not in list
```

What is confusing about this to me is that this error includes just the first letter (`f`) of the column that I want to select (`fips`). I don't know what could be causing this in Python.

I have tried loading the data in using Pandas and all the column headers appeared to be loading correctly, but I want to figure out why it isn't working using the `data.load` feature. I am able to load in a one-column CSV just fine (which is a simple workaround where I split my CSV into multiple one-column CSVs), but I'd like to get the `select` function working for multi-column CSVs for simplicity and ease of use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely at the [documentation](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/working_abstractmodels/data/dataportals.html#selecting-parameter-columns) for `select` it says the argument should be a list or tuple.  So, internally to that function, the argument is "iterated".  And, strings are *iterable* so the first "f" is being peeled off.

Solution:  If you just have one column name, put it into a 1-element list or 1-element tuple.  Note:  you need the trailing comma in a 1-element tuple or it is just interpreted as parenthesis.  Try this:

```
data.load(filename='fips.csv',select=('fips',),set=model.i)
```

Also in that same section of documentation, there is a note about loading multiple parameters at once, which might be helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know what I would do without this community.

Comment: Great.  As I mentioned to you in the other post you had, it this answered the issue, please hit the "check mark" next to the answer to close it out (and give me my meager points...lol)

Comment: OK, I may have spoken too soon. When trying your code just now, I ran into a different error. `IndexError: string index out of range`. Do you have any thoughts on what's going on? The column of the data frame I'm trying to read in has integers, not a string.

Comment: I doubt that error is coming from the load operation.  Check the line number, etc.  Print the set after it has been loaded.  If that doesn't work and you are stuck whittle it down to a minimum reproducible example, along with a couple lines of your data source so that the error can be reproduced and post a new question.

Comment: Well, maybe there is a problem with this approach overall.  I just tinkered with the "select" command and I cannot get it to load an individual set correctly.  It can do an indexed parameter as in the documentation, but I can't get it to work for a set.  You might want to consider a different data structure that is more predictable.